# A way to Binarylizable a key for ignite in python

Tags: python, binary, ignite

I am trying to use `pylibmc` to create a client for `Ignite` and after that I want to get data by key . I manage to create the client, but the problem is that the key is a `Binarylizable` object. In `java` I saw that this is an ignite class, but I didn't find any info about how can i get data from ignite using a Binarylizable key in python

```
key_object = ObjectKey()
ley = pickle.dumps(key_object)

try:
    client = pylibmc.Client(["host:port"], binary=True, password=password, username=username)
    client.get(key)
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception)
```

Is there any way to make this possible in python?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but why not use Ignite's Python API?

Comment: Because i don't know how to send via REST Api and binary key. I've already try sort of it.

Comment: The Python-Ignite API has methods for dealing with binary objects: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/python-thin-client-binary-types

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the info i will see about it.